# Replace part of URL using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have a case like this :

- `http://example.com/`
- `http://example.com/test/`
- `http://example.com/auth/`
- `http://example.com/auth/login`
- `http://example.com/auth/forget_password`

I need to change `example.com` into my IP (`1.1.10.7`) when user accessing path that containing `auth`.

The results I need are:

- `http://example.com/` => `http://example.com/`
- `http://example.com/test/` =>  `http://example.com/test/`
- `http://example.com/auth/` => `http://1.1.10.7/auth/`
- `http://example.com/auth/login` => `http://1.1.10.7/auth/login`
- `http://example.com/auth/forget_password` => `http://1.1.10.7/auth/forget_password`

I tried several times from reading on another StackOverflow question, but still not resolved.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You can try something like - `RedirectMatch 301 ^/auth/(.*) http://1.1.10.7/auth/$1`

Comment: @Kunal: That will cause a redirect loop

Comment: @anubhava Oh yeahh I missed that part thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=1.1.10.7
RewriteRule ^auth/ http://1.1.10.7%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,NE,R=301]
```